# Why is this explicit scope resolution necessary?

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, scope, visibility

Setup:

```
class A {
  public:
    void a() {}
};

class B {
  public:
    void b() {}
};

class C: public A, public B {
  public:
    void c() {}
};
```

What (I thought) I should be able to do:

```
C* foo = new C();
foo->b();
```

And I get the following linker error from GCC:

```
`... undefined reference to 'C::b(void)'`
```

If I use explicit scope resolution it works, as in:

```
C* foo = new C();
foo->B::b();
```

A, B, and C share no members with similar signatures, so I know nothing is being hidden.  Two questions:

1) Why, theoretically, am I not able to access public base class members implicitly?

2) What (if anything) in practice can I do to avoid this annoying syntax?

I can continue development with the explicit syntax (although I'd rather be rid of it) but I'm more looking to learn something here about my (apparently incorrect) knowledge of public inheritance in C++.

Cheers!

**EDIT:** Sorry, updated the sample code - some bad mistypes in my original.

**EDIT2:** Here's the (relevant parts of) the real code:
from src/creature.h:

```
#include "container.h"
#include "identifiers.h"

class Creature: public Identifiers, public Container {
  public:
    Creature( void );
    Creature( const Creature& ref );
    virtual ~Creature( void );
};
```

from src/identifier.h:

```
class Identifiers {
  public:
    Identifiers( void );
    Identifiers( const Identifiers& ref );
    ~Identifiers( void );
};
```

from src/container.h:

```
class Container {
  public:
    Container( std::string (Object::*getName)( void ) const );
    Container( const Container& ref );
    ~Container( void );

    void  add( Object* object );
    void  add( const std::list<Object*>& objects );
    void  remove( Object* object );
    void  remove( const std::list<Object*>& objects );
};
```

from src/container.cpp:

```
Container::Container( std::string (Object::*getName)( void ) const ) {
  _getName = getName;
  return;
}

Container::Container( const Container& ref ) {
  _getName = ref._getName;
  return;
}

Container::~Container( void ) {
  while ( !objectList().empty() ) {
    delete objectList().front();
    objectList().pop_front();
  }
  return;
}

void Container::add( Object* object ) {
  objectList().push_back( object );
  return;
}

void Container::add( const std::list<Object*>& objects ) {
  objectList().insert( objectList().end(), objects.begin(), objects.end() );
  return;
}

void Container::remove( Object* object ) {
  objectList().remove( object );
  return;
}

void Container::remove( const std::list<Object*>& objects ) {
  for ( std::list<Object*>::const_iterator it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it ) {
    remove( *it );
  }
  return;
}
```

from the application itself:

```
bool CmdWear::execute( Creature* creature, const std::string& args ) {
  std::list<Object*> objects;
  Object* removed = NULL;
  std::string error;

  objects = creature->searchObjects( args );

  for ( std::list<Object*>::iterator it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it ) {
    if ( creature->wear( *it, error, removed ) ) {
      creature->remove( *it );
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Notes:

1) All methods shown here are defined in their appropriate .cpp file.

2) Each associated object file compiles just fine.  Only the linker fails at the last step of linking all the object files together.

3) GCC spits out: undefined reference to `Creature::remove(Object*)' unless I qualify explicitly the scope by saying:

```
creature->Container::remove( *it );
```

**Makefile**:

```
PROJECT     = symphony
CPPC        = g++
FLAGS_DEV   = -ggdb3 -ansi -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors
LIBS        = `pcre-config --libs` `mysql_config --libs`
SRC_DIR     = src
OBJ_DIR     = obj
BIN_DIR     = .
SRC_FILES  := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES  := $(patsubst src/%.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

dev: $(OBJ_FILES)
  $(CPPC) $(LIBS) $(FLAGS_DEV) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(PROJECT)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
  $(CPPC) -c $(FLAGS_DEV) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Alex's answer below is correct; however, I think you've missed something when writing this test case, and your real code is possibly doing something slightly different. (Since you forgot to make 'foo' a pointer, the quoted error message obviously comes from some other code.)

Comment: I think you're leaving some details out.  "C foo = new C();" alone should *not compile*, as foo would need to be a pointer.

Comment: Well, now that you've changed (fixed) your code, it no longer gives the linker error you claim. So your question no longer makes sense.

Comment: Please cut and paste (don't retype) _complete_ code that demonstrates your error.

Comment: @Chris, if you're getting a linker error, your code may be fine. Let's see what your compile line looks like.  See my answer below.

Comment: Okay - added pertinent sections of the "real code" and the GCC linker error.

Comment: *Complete* code. Statements are not valid outside a function body so the snippet from the application is not valid on it's own. Where is `Creature::add(Object*)` defined? Either this *is* your problem or you haven't posted all of your code.

Comment: As in note 1) All methods shown in those snippets are defined in the appropriate .cpp file.  I'll slide them in, though, just to be sure there's not something else wonky going on.

Comment: Real code isn't necessary, as long as the minimal test case demonstrates the same problem correctly.

Comment: @Chris: Are you sure that your definition for `Creature` is accurate as the compile error indicates that you have declared a function called `remove` that hides the base class (`Container`) version?

Comment: @Charles Bailey - Thanks so much for the insight; It turns out there were declarations for remove() in Creature that I never removed when I percolated that functionality up into Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that either of the snippets that you've posted should compile.

```
class C: public A, public B {
  public
    void c();
};
```

You need a `:` after the `public` access specifier.

```
C foo = new C();
foo->b();
```

You are trying to initialized a `C` from a pointer to dynamically allocated `C` object. `.` not `->` is the correct operator to call a function on an object type. `->` is for pointer types (or objects with an overloaded `->` operator) only.

You need something like:

```
C foo;
foo.b();
```

I'm not sure how the snippet that you say works actually compiles.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a function that's not defined. gcc's telling you exactly that. And `foo::B->b();` is not valid C++. It doesn't compile with either `g++` or `cl.exe`.

If you wrote

```
public:
  void b() {}
```

it would work.

Comment: But C inherits publicly from A and B, and B does define b(void).  And this compiles on GCC 4.4.1 with the -ansi flag.

Comment: B doesn't define b(void). It only declares it.

Comment: Sorry - those methods are defined.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Chris, there is a difference between declaration and definition.  B::b() is **declared** but it is not **defined**.  Also, the correct syntax would be `foo->B::b()` and that shouldn't help you one bit, because B::b() still isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: It might be valid if `B` was a static member of `foo` with a pointer type... I don't think we've been given all the code.

Comment: Indeed, or if `foo` was a namespace type and `B` was a pointer to some class with a public member function `b()`.

I guess I meant that *given the context*, it is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
C foo = new C();
foo->b();
```

This is wrong, you probably wanted:

```
C foo;
foo.b();
```

it should work, as long as that error you're getting is not a linker error (I'm not familiar with the gcc suite). If it's a linker error it means your function doesn't have a body, so there's nothing to call.

Comment: Either will work. Though stack-allocation is preferred, this is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: No, C foo = new C(); won't work because new C() will return a pointer. In his example the definition of foo is wrong. C * foo = new C(); would work tho

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is a linker error, not a compiler error.  That implies that your code compiles -- good.  The linker is complaining because it can't find the definition of the function.  Is the definition in a different C++ file?  Perhaps there is a file B.cpp which contains:

```
#include "B.h"
void B::b() {
  // do something nifty here
}
```

and then there is a separate file C.cpp which contains:

```
#include "C.h"
C *
func() {
  C* foo = new C();
  foo->b();
  return foo;
}
```

If you only compile C.cpp, such as:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra C.cpp
```

Then you will get the linker error you see.

Perhaps you want to do a partial compilation and then link all the .o files later?

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -c C.cpp
```

Or perhaps you want to compile them all together and link at the same time?

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this out :

C *foo = new C();

And where is the function definitions ??.

Explicit scope resolution is only necessary in this case:

class A {
 public:
     void fun(){};
};

class B {
 public:
     void fun(){};
};

class C : public A , public B
{

};

int main()
{

   C c;

   c.A::fun();

}
```